# Having some problems with scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm a beginner working on an android app and I need to use a scroll view so that I can have enough space to put many questions on the screen. I set up a scroll view, but when I go to the graphical layout I can see only the first questions, and I still don't have enough space to put the rest of them.It's like I can't scroll it down to add some more. Is it possible to do it? I am using eclipse with the google android bundle installed.

Here's my XML code:

```
<ScrollView
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="Surse de venit:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        android:text="(RON)"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:text="@string/x1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/x3"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/x2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/x1txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="@string/x4"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/x2txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/x1txt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/x1txt"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/x3txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/x2txt"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/x2txt"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/x4txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/x3txt"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberSigned" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/x4txt"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:text="@string/ven"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:text="@string/y1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView7"
        android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
        android:text="Cheltuieli:"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:text="@string/y2"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: so wait you just want to be able to see it in the graphical layout and there is no problem when you run it? just add everything in the xml

Comment: `android:layout_height="408dp"`??

Comment: @tyczj I can't run it because I haven't written any code in java yet, I'm working only in XML atm. So all I have to do is to write it by myself??

Comment: @njzk2 sorry for that, just edited it

Comment: your RelativeLayout should have height set to wrap_content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need is to add `android:fillViewport="true"` to the `ScrollView` in your xml

Answer (score 0):

Scrollviews can only contain linearlayouts.
For example

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="left"
android:orientation="vertical" >
    -----code
</linearlayout>
</scrollview>
```

EDIT!
The only possibilty would be this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#2d89ef"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >
```